# Find Guide who work on more than one tour on the same day

Tags: sql, oracle

| OUTING_ID | TOUR_ID | OUTING_START | GUIDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21000167 | 100345 | 30-APR-21 | 982354 |
| 21000168 | 100345 | 16-MAY-21 | 982354 |
| 21000170 | 100348 | 17-JUN-21 | 183476 |
| 21000200 | 100411 | 21-MAY-21 | 982354 |
| 21000202 | 100411 | 03-JUN-21 | 183476 |
| 21000205 | 100419 | 21-MAY-21 | 982354 |
| 21000207 | 100437 | 07-MAY-21 | 208655 |

Above define table describe the data of outing table.

I need guide who are working on more than one tour on the same day.
I need the below data through query.

| OUTING_ID | TOUR_ID | OUTING_START | GUIDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21000200 | 100411 | 21-MAY-21 | 982354 |
| 21000205 | 100419 | 21-MAY-21 | 982354 |

I tried with many solutions but I didn't get what I want.
I tried with below query too but didn't work for me as I data want.

```
SELECT 
    "A2O".GUIDE 
FROM 
    A2_OUTING "A2O" 
WHERE 
    OUTING_START IN (SELECT OUTING_START 
                     FROM A2_OUTING 
                     GROUP BY OUTING_START 
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

I tried with this whole day and now I am frustrated doing this, please help me with this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your solution, you need to be grouping by both `outing_start` and `guide`, and it looks like you want to project more than just the `guide` column.

As mathguy pointed out in another comment, this is only valid if the time component to your `outing_start` is all the same. You can use the `trunc` function to do this if needs be.

```
SELECT outing_id, tour_id, outing_start, guide FROM A2_OUTING "A2O" WHERE (OUTING_START, guide) IN (
    SELECT OUTING_START, guide FROM A2_OUTING GROUP BY OUTING_START, guide HAVING COUNT(*)>1
);
```

An alternative solution would be to use an analytic count so that you don’t need the join.

```
SELECT outing_id, tour_id, outing_start, guide 
FROM (
SELECT outing_id, tour_id, outing_start, guide
,count(*) over (partition by outing_start, guide) cnt
 FROM A2_OUTING ) sq
Where cnt > 1
```

Comment: "so that you need the join" - what join? Did you mean "you need a subquery"?

Comment: yes I need a subquery which will provide me the data for individual guide. Means I want guide who working on different tour on same date, System don't allow to do that. One person unable to visit more than 2 tour at that same day. Do you get my point?

Comment: @mathguy I meant so you *don’t* need the join

Comment: then how it will work, how can I match individual guide with their outing_start date. Thank you for your help. I tried your updated query solution but it didn't work for me although it will return none data.

Comment: @MitaliPatel have you seen Mathguy’s comments about the time components? If my queries are returning no rows then it’s likely that there’s a varying time component do your date columns that you weren’t displaying. If that’s the case then you just need to use the `trunc` function when referring to the date column in your filter and group by or in the partition by clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`COUNT() OVER ()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COUNT.html#GUID-AEF08B79-024D-4E3A-B362-9715FB011776)**  analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT outing_id, tour_id, outing_start, guide
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY outing_start,guide) AS cnt, a.* 
          FROM a2_outing a)
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: Surely the partition should also be by "guide". Also, unless all OUTING_START are known to have midnight as the time-of-day, you will need to truncate the date in the PARTITION BY clause.